# Big difference in the cost of paying the round trip

Tags: here-api, here-fleet-telematics

The route from 46.371399% 2C2.569599 to 50.53027% 2C9.68613 costs 254.4 euros in France, and 74.2 euros back in France. Why such difference?

254.4 euros
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=jsonAttributes%3D41&app_id=&app_code=&apikey=&mode=truck%3Bfastest%3Btraffic%3Adisabled&language=en-GB&representation=overview&metricSystem=metric&routeattributes=wp%2Csc%2Csm%2Csh%2Cbb%2Clg%2Cno%2Cshape&legattributes=wp%2Cmn%2Cli%2Cle%2Ctt&maneuverattributes=po%2Csh%2Ctt%2Cle%2Cti%2Cli%2Cpt%2Cpl%2Crn%2Cnr%2Cdi&linkattributes=sh%2Cle%2Csl%2Cds%2Ctr&instructionformat=html&trailersCount=0&alternatives=0&currency=EUR&trailerType=2&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&height=4m&trailerHeight=400&vehicleWeight=8000&limitedWeight=40t&width=225&length=16.5m&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=1&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=300&fuelType=Diesel&detail=1&rollup=none%2Ccountry%3Btollsys&requestId=1631897604381&excludeCountries=CHE&truckRestrictionPenalty=strict&emissionType=6&shippedhazardousgoods=0&waypoint0=geo!46.371399%2C2.569599&waypoint1=geo!50.53027%2C9.68613&jsoncallback=H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(17)

74.2 euros
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=jsonAttributes%3D41&app_id=&app_code=&apikey=&mode=truck%3Bfastest%3Btraffic%3Adisabled&language=en-GB&representation=overview&metricSystem=metric&routeattributes=wp%2Csc%2Csm%2Csh%2Cbb%2Clg%2Cno%2Cshape&legattributes=wp%2Cmn%2Cli%2Cle%2Ctt&maneuverattributes=po%2Csh%2Ctt%2Cle%2Cti%2Cli%2Cpt%2Cpl%2Crn%2Cnr%2Cdi&linkattributes=sh%2Cle%2Csl%2Cds%2Ctr&instructionformat=html&trailersCount=0&alternatives=0&currency=EUR&trailerType=2&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&height=4m&trailerHeight=400&vehicleWeight=8000&limitedWeight=40t&width=225&length=16.5m&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=1&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=300&fuelType=Diesel&detail=1&rollup=none%2Ccountry%3Btollsys&requestId=1631897604381&excludeCountries=CHE&truckRestrictionPenalty=strict&emissionType=6&shippedhazardousgoods=0&waypoint1=geo!46.371399%2C2.569599&waypoint0=geo!50.53027%2C9.68613&jsoncallback=H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(17)

Answer (score 0):

On the way forward, the route uses the paid highway section from "Montluçon" to "Saint-Maurice", which costs 244.20€ according to the HERE API, for trucks matching specified input parameters.
According to the [current pricesheet](https://voyage.aprr.fr/sites/default/files/2021-08/tarifs-peage-aprr-2021-new.pdf) from the French highway operator APRR, this section costs indeed 244.20€. See page 177, vehicle column *Class 4*. Therefore the high amount is not a data error.

The high difference comes from the fact that on the way back, the route exits the paid section much earlier at "Chalon-Sud", so the section to pay is "Saint-Maurice" to "Chalon-Sud", which costs 64€ for *Class 4* vehicles.

Comment: Saint-Maurice is 700km away, and we use only a short section of this highway.  If you use Map & Guide (PTV) the calculate cost on this section would be 0€

Comment: The returned route is referring to the Toll of Saint-Maurice on A36 highway, at coordinates 47.42525,6.67099. The paid section on the first route is over 400km, then the route goes to Germany through Mulhouse (FR). On the return route, the paid section in France is "only" 200km as the suggested route is different, it enters France through Saarbrücken (DE). On top of that French highway prices are not linear, when projected to the distance to ride.

Comment: Can you link to the calculation returned by PTV Map & Guide, or if not available online, a way to reproduce that route calculation?